# Oracle Error on exchange partition ORA-14099. How to check rows

Tags: oracle

I get error `'ORA-14099: all rows in table do not qualify for specified partition'`

1. I create new empty partition `p1` on Hash Partitioned Table `t1`
2. Create swap table `CREATE TABLE t2 AS SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE 1 = 0`
3. Do exchange empty partition and empty swap table `alter table t1 exchange partition p1 with table t2 with validation`
4. Load data to swap table
5. Do exchange empty partition and swap table with data with validation `alter table t1 exchange partition p1 with table t2 with validation`
6. Get error

If I use it without validation, It will work
How to check which rows are invalid?

Comment: I found answers https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-F023D3ED-262F-4B19-950A-D3C8F8CDB4F4.htm#VLDBG1270

Comment: With hash partitioning, a row is placed into a partition based on the result of passing the partitioning key into a hashing algorithm.

Using this approach, data is randomly distributed across the partitions rather than grouped.